# Kaltura captions: set default language to None or otherwise force them off?

Tags: captions, closed-captions, kaltura

Using the Kaltura player FlashVars parameter, it's possible to set the default language to English or other languages. We'd like to set it to `None`, to force captions off, but there does not appear to be a way do this. Are we mistaken?

Here's how to set the language to English as a FlashVar:
`closedCaptionsOverPlayer.defaultLanguageKey=en`

Instead of a value of `en`, we have tried `off`, `null`, `none`, `''`, `0`, and `nothing`, but none of those had any apparent effect: captions still appear when the player loads a video.

The test / preview tool related to the use of captions (http://kgit.html5video.org/pulls/421/docs/CaptionsKalturaApi) has no choice for forcing them off, as far as we can see.

-Ken

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a player with the `cc` plugin not loaded.
2. You can the kdpReady notification and send 
   `kdp.sendNotification('showHideClosedCaptions');` to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set in KMC. Click Entry->Captions->Make default, to any file you want. This leads to show the captions which you liked or else nothing appears as caption in player.